# Read a 2D array with fileio in C++

Tags: c++, arrays

I have a problem with my read function, which only reads a file partially.
For example, if the size of my array is 4*4, my function only reads pixels from

pixels[0(pixels[0][1],pixels[0][2],pixels[0][3],pixels[0][4])

However, I want it to read all 16 pixels.

The field of my class is:

```
unsigned int cols;
unsigned int rows;
uint8_t** pixels;
```

Here is my load function:

```
int Image::load(const char* filename) {
    //int count=0;
    ifstream inFile(filename);
    if (!inFile) {
        cerr<<"unable to open file";
        return 1;
    }
    inFile>>cols;
    inFile>>rows;
    cout<<cols;
    cout<<rows;

    pixels=new uint8_t*[cols];
    for(int i=0;i<cols;i++){
        pixels[i]=new uint8_t[rows];
    }
    for(int i=0;i<cols;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<rows;j++){
            inFile>>pixels[i][j];
            cout<<(uint8_t)(pixels[i][j]);
        }
    }
    //cout<<count;
    inFile.close();
    return 0;
}
```

The file I am reading have cols, rows, and pixels;

```
4   4
0   0   16
0   1   16
0   2   16
0   3   16
1   0   16
1   1   16
1   2   16
1   3   16
2   0   16
2   1   16
2   2   16
2   3   16
3   0   16
3   1   16
3   2   16
3   3   16
```

Comment: Please provide a reproducible code example along with a file example, it should help.

Comment: Why not `std::vector<vector<uint8_t>>`?

Comment: You should add error checking. Also, just stwpoing through your code with debugger should tell what's wrong quickly.